# Angle between lines in 3D space

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, tkz-euclide

In my following codes:

1. How can I create a beautiful mark angle for DCE angle?
2. How can I change position ALPHA in front of BAC angle in space?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=3,
    tdplot_main_coords,
    axis/.style={->,blue,thick},
    vector/.style={-stealth,red,very thick},
    vector guide/.style={dashed,red,thick}
  ]

    % standard tikz coordinate definition using x, y, z coords
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (1,0,2);
    \coordinate (B) at (.5,.86603,3);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,0,1);
    \coordinate (D) at (.5,.86603,0);
    \coordinate (E) at (1,0,3);
    \coordinate (F) at (0,0,3);
    \coordinate (H) at (1,0,0);

    % tikz-3dplot coordinate definition using r, theta, phi coords
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{.8}{55}{60}

    % draw axes
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

    \fill[gray!20] (O) -- (H) -- (E) -- (F) -- cycle;
    % \fill[green!50] (O) -- (D) -- (B) -- (F) -- cycle;
    \fill[blue!20] (B) -- (E) -- (F) -- cycle;
    \fill[blue!20] (O) -- (D) -- (H) -- cycle;

    \fill[black] (O) circle (1pt) node[right] {$O$};
    \fill[black] (A) circle (1pt) node[left] {$A$};
    \fill[black] (B) circle (1pt) node[right] {$B$};
    \fill[black] (C) circle (1pt) node[right] {$C$};
    \fill[black] (D) circle (1pt) node[right] {$D$};
    \fill[black] (E) circle (1pt) node[left] {$E$};
    \fill[black] (F) circle (1pt) node[right] {$F$};
    \fill[black] (H) circle (1pt) node[below] {$H$};

    \draw[ultra thick] (O) -- (F);
    \draw[thick] (O) -- (H);
    \draw[thick] (O) -- (D);
    \draw[thick] (D) -- (H);
    \draw[thick] (H) -- (A);
    \draw[thick] (A) -- (E);
    \draw[thick] (F) -- (B);
    \draw[thick] (B) -- (E);
    \draw[thick] (E) -- (F);
    \draw[thick,red] (B) -- (A);
    \draw[thick,red] (A) -- (C);
    \draw[thick,red] (C) -- (D);
    \draw[thick] (B) -- (D);

    \tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange,size=0.2cm,opacity=.4](C,A,B)
    \tkzLabelAngle[above left,pos=0.3](C,A,B){$\alpha$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange,size=0.15cm,opacity=.4](A,C,D)
    \tkzLabelAngle[above left,pos=0.3,font=\small](A,C,D){$\alpha$}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My code's result.

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Let me take the two subquestions in reverse order.

## Placing labels with `\tkzLabelAngle`

`\tkzLabelAngle` places labels on the line bisecting the angle.   A `pos` argument gives the position of the label on that line as a proportion of the standard length.  Additional arguments such as `above` are then relative to the point specified by the `pos` argument.  To move the label further in the direction `above` you write something like `above=5pt`.  Here is a right angle labelled at different `pos` values:

[image: Sample pos arguments]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
  \coordinate (A) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (0,1);
  \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);
  \tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange,size=0.3,opacity=0.4](A,B,C);
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.1](A,B,C){$0.1$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.3](A,B,C){$0.3$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](A,B,C){$0.5$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5,above](A,B,C){$0.5$ above}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5,above=20pt](A,B,C){$0.5$ above}
  \tkzLabelAngle(A,B,C){$1$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately `tkz-euclide` will sometimes get the wrong direction for the bisector:

[image: Sample wrong bisector]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
  \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
  \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (1,-1);
  \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);
  \tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange,size=0.3,opacity=0.4](A,B,C);
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.1](A,B,C){$0.1$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.3](A,B,C){$0.3$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5](A,B,C){$0.5$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5,above](A,B,C){$0.5$ above}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.5,above=20pt](A,B,C){$0.5$ above}
  \tkzLabelAngle(A,B,C){$1$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is what happen is in your angle at `A`.  You can compensate for this by specifying negative arguments to `pos` instead.  I would probably to just use ordinary `tikz` node placement for this, as in the code given below.

## Mark for angle DCE

You can use the same approach as for the other angles.  However, there is a lot going at the node `C`, so positioning needs to be adjusted.  I also suggest adding guide edges for the angle (dashed) and slightly rotating the view to help.  Putting this together gives:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{125}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=3,
    tdplot_main_coords,
    axis/.style={->,blue,thick},
    vector/.style={-stealth,red,very thick},
    vector guide/.style={dashed,red,thick}
  ]

    % standard tikz coordinate definition using x, y, z coords
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (1,0,2);
    \coordinate (B) at (.5,.86603,3);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,0,1);
    \coordinate (D) at (.5,.86603,0);
    \coordinate (E) at (1,0,3);
    \coordinate (F) at (0,0,3);
    \coordinate (H) at (1,0,0);

    % tikz-3dplot coordinate definition using r, theta, phi coords
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{.8}{55}{60}

    % draw axes
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

    \fill[gray!20] (O) -- (H) -- (E) -- (F) -- cycle;
    \fill[blue!20] (B) -- (E) -- (F) -- cycle;
    \fill[blue!20] (O) -- (D) -- (H) -- cycle;

    \tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange,size=0.2cm,opacity=.4](C,A,B);
    \draw (A) node[right=2pt,font=\small] {$\alpha$};
    \tkzMarkAngle[fill=orange,size=0.15cm,opacity=.4](A,C,D);
    \draw (C) node[below left,font=\small] {$\gamma$};
    \tkzMarkAngle[fill=green,size=0.13cm,opacity=.6](D,C,E);
    \draw (C) node[right,font=\small] {$\beta$};

    \draw[ultra thick] (O) -- (F);
    \draw[thick] (O) -- (H);
    \draw[thick] (O) -- (D);
    \draw[thick] (D) -- (H);
    \draw[thick] (H) -- (A);
    \draw[thick] (A) -- (E);
    \draw[thick] (F) -- (B);
    \draw[thick] (B) -- (E);
    \draw[thick] (E) -- (F);
    \draw[thick,red] (B) -- (A);
    \draw[thick,red] (A) -- (C);
    \draw[thick,red] (C) -- (D);
    \draw[thick] (B) -- (D);
    \draw[thin,dashed] (D) -- (C) -- (E);

    \fill[black] (O) circle (1pt) node[above right] {$O$};
    \fill[black] (A) circle (1pt) node[left] {$A$};
    \fill[black] (B) circle (1pt) node[right] {$B$};
    \fill[black] (C) circle (1pt) node[above right=7pt] {$C$};
    \fill[black] (D) circle (1pt) node[right] {$D$};
    \fill[black] (E) circle (1pt) node[left] {$E$};
    \fill[black] (F) circle (1pt) node[above right] {$F$};
    \fill[black] (H) circle (1pt) node[below] {$H$};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You had two "alpha"s in your diagram, so I have renamed one of them "gamma".  I have also change the printing order, so that the dot labels are uppermost in the diagram.  As mentioned above, I decided not to use `\tkzLabelAngle` but just ordinary node placement for the labelling of the angles.

Comment: Thanks. Realy I want that orange region of gamma's angle place in the plane that points A, C , D are on it. How??

Comment: tikz is not really 3d, it converts everything to their 2d projections at the start.  You can fake it by passing an `xscale` option to `\tkzLabelAngle` making the marker elliptical on the paper rather than circular.  Try e.g. `xscale=0.9`.